# How to upgrade R on CentOS

Tags: r, linux, centos, redhat

I am running version 3.6 of R on CentOS (CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)). Is there a simple way to upgrade R to the latest version and upgrade all the installed libraries?

EPEL repository on my machine is `epel-release-7-13.noarch` and by default, it installs version 3.6 of R.

I was referring to the following post -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r but the package `installr` is only available for Windows.

There is another post ([How to upgrade R in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu)) that describes how to upgrade R on Ubuntu, however some of these commands do not work on CentOS.

I am sure there must be a painless way to upgrade R in CentOS.

Answer (score 2):

I think this post may help you:

[How can I install the newest version of R (currently 4.0.0) on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801750/how-can-i-install-the-newest-version-of-r-currently-4-0-0-on-centos)

At this point, I'm sure you've solved the problem, but perhaps this will help others.

Official centOS instructions are located here:
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/fedora

With centOS, there's not an easy solution, but this may be the best you can find on the topic.